# Замена SDK на KDevelop при работе с Zynq (xilinx)

Tags: linux, c, sdk, vivado

Всем привет! Нужно перейти с SDK на KDevelop, для разработки бараметальной части ПО для матрицы из семейства Zynq 7K.
Создал "Hell world" проект средствами Vivado 2016.4, экспортировал в SDK И проверил что там он собирается без проблем.

Следующим шагом хочу перейти с SDK на Kdevelop, но ума не приложу, как настроить эту среду разработки на работу с данным проектом?

Я не прошу пошаговой помощи в настройке (хотя если такая будет я буду благодарен). Мне бы хотя бы пинок в нужную сторону.
В общем, прошу помощи в настройке. С чего начать, может какую-либо дорожную карту обрисуете?
ОС Kubuntu 16

Создал проект в KDevelop. Я так понимаю, нужно где-то прописать пути до исходников? При этом Vivado нагенерировала кучу своих с/h файлов. Полагаю, там где есть файл, который связывае все эти сорцы? Не в ручную же мне набивать все пути до файлов, который автоматом сгенерировались? Также не ясно, какие именно файлы нужно добавлять в проект? Понятно, что c/h. мой проект называется test. Я полагаю, что нужно работать с содержимым папки test.sdk?